# Getting DNS mapping with multiple apps in nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, webserver

I plan on running multiple apps from a single nginx server with separate domain names. For example I have purchased the domain(ex test.com). For the apps I expect app1 will be visible on app1.test.com and app2 will be visible on app2.test.com

The conf files for app1 would be:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app1.test.com;

  location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/sites/app1/static;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/app1.socket;
  }
}
```

The conf file for app2 would be:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app2.test.com;

  location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/sites/app2/static;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/app2.socket;
  }
}
```

If the ip address of the server is X.X.X.X, then how and what do I map to app1.test.com and app2.test.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will in itself work, no changes are needed. All that needs to be done is to map the server_name to the domain name in your name server.